# What is this asking? Show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if for all $u,v \in W$ and $c\in \mathbb{F}, u+v \in W$ and $cu \in W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't know if others have this problem but there are times when I read problems and I simply don't understand what the problem is asking me to prove.  Take this problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and let $W$ be a subset of $V$.  Show that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if for all $u,v \in W$ and $c\in \mathbb{F}, u+v \in W$ and $cu \in W$

What exactly is this asking me to prove?  I know that a subspace of a vector space $V$ is a subset $W$ of $V$ that has three properties:

- The zero vector of $V$ is in $W$.
- $W$ is closed under addition.  i.e.  If $u,v \in W$ then $u+v \in W$
- $W$ is closed under scaler multiplication.  i.e. If $u \in W$ and $c \in \mathbb{F}$ then $cu \in W$

Since this is "if and only if" I know I have to prove both ways.  But, what exactly am I proving?  It seems to me that for the forward direction I can assume that W is a subspace of V and therefore it has all of the properties I need already.  i.e.  nothing to prove except possibly that $0$ is in $W$. (easy)

For the backward implication I can assume for all $u,v \in W$ and $c\in \mathbb{F}$ that $u+v \in W$ and $cu \in W$.  Once again it seems that there is nothing to prove except possibly that $0$ is in $W$. (easy)

Or is this question asking me to prove that $W$ is a vector space?  What am I missing?  Please don't do the proof.  I don't want the proof.  Just some clarification on what exactly I am trying to prove.

Thanks,

IdleMathGuy

Comment: In fact proving that zero is there is not easy at all. It is impossible. The exercise, as written, is faulty. The empty set satisfies these two conditions, but is not a subspace.

Comment: @IttayWeiss maybe the empty set is excluded?

Comment: Once you assume the space is non-empty, you need to check all the axioms of vector spaces are inherited by the subspace.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, of course. That's *exactly* what Ittay just wrote. The empty set is **never** a vector space *by definition* .

Comment: For me, these properties are the *definition* of a subspace.

Comment: @Bernard That is what is confusing.  It is like the question is saying "assume that W has the properties of a subspace now prove that it is a subspace".

Comment: @Bernard It can't be since there's no condition that $\;W\neq\emptyset\;$ and **it must be there** , as Ittay wrote above.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes since this is "if and only if" you have to prove both ways.

Assuming that the subspace in not empty, first assume three properties:

- The zero vector of $V$ is in $W$.
- $W$ is closed under addition.  i.e.  If $u,v \in W$ then $u+v \in W$
- $W$ is closed under scaler multiplication.  i.e. If $u \in W$ and $c \in \mathbb{F}$ then $cu \in W$

and show that for all $u,v \in W$ and $c\in \mathbb{F}, u+v \in W$ and $cu \in W$.

Then assume that for all $u,v \in W$ and $c\in \mathbb{F}, u+v \in W$ and $cu \in W$ and show that all the three properties hold.

Comment: Isn't assuming the zero vector redundant? $W$ is already non empty and closed under multiplication (i.e. by $0$)

Comment: @Myridium why rendundant? To prove the equivalence you need to check that all the definition properties hold.

Comment: It’s redundant: let $W$ not be empty and $u\in W$ and $c=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How can we assume W is not empty?  If W is a subset of V it could just as well be the empty set....